git keep asking me my ssh key passphrase since upgrade from 22.4 to 24.4
All is in the title.
I can't find why everytime I git pull or git push using ssh, my key passphrase is mandatory since it wasn't in my previous ubuntu versions.
I didn't change anything, just let ubuntu upgrade from 22 to 24.

Did you use ssh-agent before? See this: https://superuser.com/a/990447/1529988

Where do you start ssh-agent? In e.g. your .bashrc or .bash_profile?

I don't know, I don't think I had done anything. I just installed git, set my key in my gitlab and it was fine. Also I use zsh. Maybe something changed in bash and is not in my zsh

cat .bashrc | grep ssh or cat .zshrc | grep ssh doesn't return anything. I don't have a .bash_profile file

Do you have an ssh-key? Check ls ~/.ssh So I know if you are giving the ssh keyphrase or if it is e.g. the remote asking for a password.

I do have, it's the key passsphrase that is requested

Try re-configuring ssh-agent.

Manually start the ssh-agent in the background of all shell instances.

eval $(ssh-agent -s)


Add the ssh-key which you have configured your remote with:

ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key>

If that worked, also do the following:

Add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc slightly modified from source.

Make sure that you replace <key> as in step 2.

SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/agent-environment"

function start_agent {
    echo "Initialising new SSH agent..."
    ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' >"$SSH_ENV"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "$SSH_ENV"
    . "$SSH_ENV" >/dev/null
    ssh-add <key>
}

# Source SSH settings, if applicable

if [ -f "$SSH_ENV" ]; then
    . "$SSH_ENV" >/dev/null
    #ps $SSH_AGENT_PID doesn't work under Cygwin
    ps -ef | grep $SSH_AGENT_PID | grep ssh-agent$ >/dev/null || {
        start_agent
    }
else
    start_agent
fi

This version is especially nice since it will see if you've already
started ssh-agent and, if it can't find it, will start it up and store
the settings so that they'll be usable the next time you start up a
shell.


it works but it's still annoying. With that script it's asked me to enter my key passphrase everytime I start a terminal

Hmm, it really shouldn't. As it should pick up the already running instance. I just tried it on my Ubuntu 24.04 instance.

If you open a new terminal and write ps -ef | grep ssh-agent, do you see any running? If multiple, try to kill all of them kill -9 <pid> and retry.

Also, output the contents of ~/.ssh/agent-environment and compare the pid under the variable SSH_AGENT_PID to the pids of from the ps -ef | grep ssh-agent command

@jona303 Do you have any updates?
